# The specified value does not conform to the required format or my date-picker becomes unassailable

Tags: date, jquery-ui, materialize

**The specified value "2018-04-01T00:00:00.000Z" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"**

I found where to format the date for [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/pickers.html) in the initiation options, but now my date picker disappears.

```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
      $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
      $('.datepicker').datepicker('yyyy-MM-dd');
    });
  </script>
```

```
.. since they both call className .datepicker, I wonder if Materialize & JQuery are causing a conflict

```
<div className = "input-field" >
<input type="date" class="datepicker" date = {this.state.date_planted} name = "date_planted" ref = "date_planted" value = {this.state.date_planted} onChange = {this.handleInputChange} />
                    <label htmlFor = "date_planted" ></label>
</div>
<div className = "input-field" >
<input type="text" className="datepicker" date = {this.state.date_last_checked} name = "date_last_checked" ref = "date_last_checked"  value = {this.state.date_last_checked} onChange = {this.handleInputChange} />
                    <label htmlFor = "date_last_checked" ></label>
</div>
```

If I change input type to text, it prefills with the correct date, but my datepicker is unavailable.
If I leave the input type as date, then it prefills to "***mm/dd/yyyy***" like it has no info to reference.

[image: capturedatepicker]

https://github.com/TurtleWolf/Food_Liberation_Front
https://food-liberation-front.herokuapp.com
 [image: Codeship Status for TurtleWolf/Food_Liberation_Front]

Comment: reformulating my question.. or maybe a new one. It's actually giving me the date picker, as long as I reload the page. I think it's a classic case of the page ready firing before the SPA is finished loading

Comment: Did you get this addressed?